# 'return' outside function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is this giving me the error `'return' outside function`?

```
Result = ""
char = ""

    # Let char loop over each character in the input string

a = list(s)
for i in range (0, len(s)):

        # If this char is a letter:

    if (type(a[i])=='str'):

            # Set char_low to be char converted to lower case

        char_low = a.lower()
        print a

            # Note: the next 5 lines do not need to be changed -
            #  they will modify the character as necessary
    if char_low <= 'm':
        dist = 13
    else:
         dist = -13
    char = chr(ord(char) + dist)
        # Push char onto the end of the result

    result = result + char

    # Return the encrypted text

return result
```

Comment: Please make sure you post your code with the correct indentation (this is particularly important for Python...).  Code blocks must be indented by an additional four spaces to render as a preformatted block in markdown, you can indent a whole block appropriately by selecting it and then using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 9):

Well, because the return is outside function.

Comment: This is the answer OP deserves, but not the one he needs right now...

Answer (score 5):

The `return` statement can only be used within a function definition, e.g.:

```
def myfunc():
    result = 1
    return result
```

You probably either want to use `sys.exit(result)` if the result is an exit code, or more likely, print the result to the console, in which case just use `print(result)`.